# How do I get badge to reset when the app is minimized?

Tags: flutter

We need some help with the flutter app badge.

We are completing a chat app in Flutter that runs on Firebase.

We want the app to reset its badge to Zero when a user checked all the unread messages and minimized the app. Currently, the reset is not happening. This is our screenplay.

[Our Screenplay](https://youtu.be/ws6mqPviWpM)

We use flutter_app_badger with this code:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {  
    switch (state) {  
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:  
    log("MyApp: AppLifecycaeState.resumed"); 
        FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();  
    break;  
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:  
        updateMyActiveStatus(false);  
        log("MyApp: AppLifecycleState.paused");  
    break;  
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:  
        log("MyApp: AppLifecycleState.inactive");  
    break;  
    case AppLifecycleState.detached: 
        log("MyApp: 
        AppLifecycleState.detached");  
    break;  
    default:  
    break;  
}
```

We also tried this code:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
        case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
            log("MyApp: AppLifecycaeState.resumed");
        break;  
        case AppLifecycleState.paused: 
            updateMyActiveStatus(false); 
                log("MyApp: AppLifecycleState.paused"); 
                FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
            break; 
        case AppLifecycleState.inactive: 
                log("MyApp: AppLifecycleState.inactive"); 
            break; 
        case AppLifecycleState.detached: l
            log("MyApp: AppLifecycleState.detached"); 
        break; 
        default: 
        break; 
}
```

Neither seems to work.

We read that the Flutter App Badger is not fully compatible with all Android devices but it should work with Samsung, HTC and many Android brands.

In our testing, we use Samsung.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I don't see any code, but that might be because you posted it as an answer. Please **edit** your question to replace the screenshots with the code as text by clicking the `edit` link under it.

Comment: Frank, I added back the code replacing the screenshot with the codes. Any insights you can provide is greatly appreciated.